# How to bind a physical network device to dom0 or domU only in RHEL5 cobbler deployed systems?

Tags: virtualization, rhel5, nic, resource-management, cobbler

I have a physical machine with two nics.

I already have a fully working cobbler server and I am able to deploy a bare metal or dom0 server in a few minutes. My target OS is RHEL5.

My goal is **to deploy a *dom0* installation in which only eth0 is up and configured** (I can already do it now), **and a number of *domUs* that are only bound to the other physical nic, eth1**.

I can assign a different IP for each domU if necessary, of course.

Anybody can point out a link to documentation or an idea to accomplish my task?

The reason of my intent is security, dom0 would be only reachable by a management network, while domUs will only live on public network.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found (only now unfortunately) a cobbler doc explaining how to do the job in a cobbler/koan way:

- https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/wiki/VirtNetworkingSetupForUseWithKoan

This is a very good starting point for me, I'm going to implement it.

The solution arrived from RHEL5 docs for xen libvirt virtualization:
http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5.4/html/Virtualization_Guide/chap-Virtualization-Pre_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_5.4_Xen_networking.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a bridge in the dom0, connect eth1 in the dom0 to that, and then configure the domUs to connect to the bridge as well.

Comment: Uhm, any pragmatic way to do it in cobbler? Moreover, why the need for a custom bridge to be shared by every domU?

Comment: I know nothing about cobbler, never touched and I hopefully never will.  It's not a "custom" bridge, it's how you're supposed to do switched network in a virtualised environment.

Comment: So it is already what cobbler does.